# android: how to access from activity A a non static public function of activity B at runtime?

Tags: android, function, android-activity

Does anyone know in android how you can call a non static public function of an activity from another activity ?

example : activity A want to access public function toto of activity B

thanks

Comment: please, describe the case why you need this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

case 1: if you are executing yours activitys into an activitygroup, then you can obtain the interested activity instance   from LocalActivityManager doing something like this `((Youractivity)getLocalactivityManager.getActivity(yourActivityId)).performYourMethod(...)`

Case 2: if you aren't running your activitys into an activitygroup, then you can use the activity B method through broadcast, is other way to perform inter activity communication.

Cheer